# Why the else statement always runs?

Tags: python, if-statement

I've been making a basic calculator with Python and I have come across this issue. After the calculations are made, "Invalid Number" ***always*** prints.

```
print("Select an action ")
print("1.) Add")
print("2.) Subtract")
print("3.) Multiply")
print("4.) Divide")
ac = int(input(">>>"))
print("First number :")
fn = float(input(">>>"))
print("Second number :")
sn = float(input(">>>"))

if ac == 1:
    print(fn + sn)
if ac == 2:
    print(fn - sn)
if ac == 3:
    print(fn * sn)
if ac == 4:
    print(fn / sn)
else:
    print("Invalid Number")
    print("Press enter to continue")
    input()
```

An example (wrong) output is:

```
Select an action 
1.) Add
2.) Subtract
3.) Multiply
4.) Divide
>>>1
First number :
>>>2
Second number :
>>>3
5.0
Invalid Number
Press enter to continue
```

How can I fix that so "Invalid Number" only prints when it should?

Comment: You should be doing `if...elif`, not those separate `if` blocks. And I wonder what that single `input("")` is supposed to do

Comment: I'd recommend fixing your indentation *and using elifs*.

Comment: else is always running, as a result of one of your conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has got something to do with how you have structured your code, consider this with `if...elif`:

```
print("Select an action ")
print("1.) Add")
print("2.) Subtract")
print("3.) Multiply")
print("4.) Divide")
ac = int(input(">>>"))
print("First number :")
fn = float(input(">>>"))
print("Second number :")
sn = float(input(">>>"))

if ac == 1:
    print(fn + sn)
elif ac == 2:
    print(fn - sn)
elif ac == 3:
    print(fn * sn)
elif ac == 4:
    print(fn / sn)
else:
    print("Invalid Number")
    print("Press enter to continue")
    input()
```

---

**Explanation:** Before, you were checking for `ac == 1` **and** `ac == 4` which cannot both be true, so the second `else` statement was executed as well. This can be omitted with the `if..elif` construction: once, one of the earlier comparisons become true, the rest is not executed anymore.

Answer (score 3):

#### With Python 3.10+ you can use the [match](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/) statement:

```py
match ac:
    case 1:
        ...
    case 2:
        ...
    case 3:
        ...
    case 4:
        ...
    case _:  # default
        ...
```

#### Before Python 3.10

You shoud use `elif`:

```
if ac == 1:
    ...
elif ac == 2:
    ...
elif ac == 3:
    ...
elif ac == 4:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to replace second and further `if` with `elif`:

```
if ac == 1:
...
elif ac == 2:
...   
if ac == 3:
...        
if ac == 4:
...        
else:
...
```

And "Invalid Number" will not be printed after each calculation.

Comment: But you only changed the second `if`. Does the code mismatch your explanation or the other way around?